# How to get php variable inside angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, validation

When i submit this form submits, it calls itself, so this is a simple form validation im trying to do with some extra functions with AngularJs.

So i want to get the value which i type in the input element called "name", to my AngularJs script inside the MainController. 
So I tried to put ng-model inside the input element, and pass the returned value from php, but then it doesnt work.
So can anyone help me to do this. 
Below is the Plunker for my project

http://tinyurl.com/ozq8fo7

Comment: shouldn't the code in the index.php page be set inside a <script> tag?

Comment: Is it so? I dont have much idea about this bro.. Why experts are not helping in this? cant they see this thread?

Comment: if it's javascript generated by a your php page, then yes, it needs to be in a script tag. A reason people might not be helping is because on stackoverflow people expect you provide your code in a "<code>" block and if you provide a link then it should be a working piece of code. So in your code block you should comment what you are having issues with and ask how to solve it.

Comment: I have provided the plunker link for the whole code.. That is that tinyurl, i could not put the direct plunker link becase, it showed some error when submitting the thread.. THANKS...